# Magento 2 magnifier issue

Tags: magento2, php, product-images

[image: Image ss]

A purchased theme of Magento 2 gives us errors continuously, and one of them is the product magnifier isn't working as the way it should work. I have pointed out a strange url for the product image and guess this is resulted not to work the magnifier.